# Excel Function Error

Tags: excel, function, text

I am trying to create a cell from a Excel to show three values depending of a number from another cell. The function I use is `=IF(H4<100;(TEXT(Probabil));(IF(H4<50;(TEXT(Sigur));(TEXT(Da))))`

NOTE: The function outputs are in Romanian.
Probabil means possible, Sigur means sure and Da means yes.

I tried to use `"` before and after the string values. I tried to put `(` and `)` before and after the TEXT functions and it resulted to the function above.

I saw in the function syntax `=TEXT(String;Type)`. I think the `Type` is required... what values can I put in that place?

- Sorry for my English, I'm Romanian.
- I am using WPS Spreadsheets to create Excel files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand that you are trying to achieve, the logic is wrong. I would suggest =IF(H4<50;"Sigur";IF(H4<100;"Probabil";"Da")) Note I removed the "text" function - the double quotes are enough.

Comment: I did some modifications with your advices and it resulted to this: `=IF(H4>100;"Nu";IF(H4>100;"Mai ai";IF(H4>0;"Probabil";IF(H4=0;"Da"))))` where `Mai ai`means `Still not`. Now the function works. Thanks!

Comment: if it works then fine, but what you show H4>100 is evaluated to "Nu" but also H4>100 is evaluated to "Mai ai" which it will mean if h4 is set to 105 then the result is "Nu" and if h4 is set to 95 then the result is "Probabil", so it never gets to evaluate to "Mai ai"...